# What is the use of python code in crontab in centos 7 while auto renewing certificates?

Tags: python, cron, centos7, certbot

I am going to set crontab for auto renewal of lets-encrypt certificate. I have centos7.

Following is my command for crontab.

```
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && certbot renew
```

I know only thing is `certbot renew`  will renew the certificate prior expiry date. And `0 0,12 * * *` is a cron time, this cron will run noon & midnight per day.

What is the use of this python command? 
Simply I don't know following part of cron.

`python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)'`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the same code will run on any vaguely U*x-like system so this is by no means CentOS specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sleeps for on average half an hour, presumably to prevent all bots in the world from hitting the server exactly on the hour when they want an update.

The argument to `time.sleep()` is a number of seconds, and the randomization picks a value between 0 and 3600.

If you had Bash you could do something similar with `sleep $((RANDOM/10))`; but `cron` jobs by definition run `/bin/sh`, not Bash. (`RANDOM` returns an integer between 0 and 32767 - the proper divisor would be something like 9.1; but Bash only supports integer arithmetic.)

Comment: Does that means my cron will not run on exact time?

Comment: The cron job itself runs exactly when you said; this is to delay the execution of the `certbot` command within that cron job to not run immediately

Comment: > "delay the execution of the certbot command within that cron job"; does it mean that if my cert expires and that cron job will not run immediately and I will have to wait for a random time to have my cert renewed?

Comment: @emeraldhieu This cron job runs twice a day, your certificate is updated only if it's about to expire. A certificate is considered about to expire when there are less than 30 days left before its expiration. Certificates are issued for 90 days. So in a normal world, your certificate will be updated every 60 days. The possible hour delay doesn't matter when you have 30 days to update it.

Answer (score 1):

`random.random()` returns a float between 0 to 1 (excluding). So, `random.random() * 3600` will return any value between 0 to 3600 (excluding), and `time.sleep` will sleep for that much *seconds*.

Rgarding the full command, if the `python` command succeeds (`&&`), `certbot renew` will be run.